# Missing spark partition column in partition table

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am creating a partitioned parquet file in HDFS with a datasource.

The datasource looks like:

```
scala> sqlContext.sql("select * from parquetFile").show()
+--------+-----------------+
|area_tag|              vin|
+--------+-----------------+
|       0|LSKG5GC19BA210794|
|       0|LSKG5GC15BA210372|
|       0|LSKG5GC18BA210107|
|       0|LSKG4GC16BA211971|
|       0|LSKG4GC19BA210233|
|       0|LSKG5GC17BA210017|
|       0|LSKG4GC19BA211785|
|       0|LSKG4GC15BA210004|
|       0|LSKG4GC12BA211739|
|       0|LSKG4GC18BA210238|
|       0|LSKG4GC13BA210261|
|       0|LSKG5GC16BA210106|
|       0|LSKG4GC1XBA210287|
|       0|LSKG4GC10BA210265|
|       0|LSKG5GC10CA210118|
|       0|LSKG5GC16BA212289|
|       0|LSKG5GC1XBA211016|
|       0|LSKG5GC15CA210194|
|       0|LSKG5GC12CA210119|
|       0|LSKG4GC19BA211379|
+--------+-----------------+
```

I create partition with the following commands (I did it in spark shell):

```
scala>val df1 = sqlContext.sql("select * from parquetFile  where area_tag=0 ")
scala>df1.write.parquet("/tmp/test_table3/area_tag=0")
scala>val p1 = sqlContext.read.parquet("/tmp/test_table3")
```

When I print the data by loading from the partitioned table, it shows:

```
scala> p1.show()
+--------+-----------------+
|area_tag|              vin|
+--------+-----------------+
|        |LSKG5GC19BA210794|
|        |LSKG5GC15BA210372|
|        |LSKG5GC18BA210107|
|        |LSKG4GC16BA211971|
|        |LSKG4GC19BA210233|
|        |LSKG5GC17BA210017|
|        |LSKG4GC19BA211785|
|        |LSKG4GC15BA210004|
|        |LSKG4GC12BA211739|
|        |LSKG4GC18BA210238|
|        |LSKG4GC13BA210261|
|        |LSKG5GC16BA210106|
|        |LSKG4GC1XBA210287|
|        |LSKG4GC10BA210265|
|        |LSKG5GC10CA210118|
|        |LSKG5GC16BA212289|
|        |LSKG5GC1XBA211016|
|        |LSKG5GC15CA210194|
|        |LSKG5GC12CA210119|
|        |LSKG4GC19BA211379|
+--------+-----------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

The partition column was missing. What happened with the column, is it a bug?

Comment: Why do you include partitioning column in the output and not `select vin from parquetFile  where area_tag=0`?

Comment: Because I need to exe SQL like select count(*), area_tag from p1 group by area_tag.